# Why is this input not being disabled?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Every now and then I get something weird in angular and I am just stumped. Can't understand why it doesn't work.

This is my JavaScript

```
angular.module('myApp',[]);


angular.module('myApp').controller('myCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.page = { myModel : 'helloWorld' }
})

angular.module('myApp').directive('myDirective', function(){
  return {
    template: '<input ng-model="data" ng-disabled="{{disabled}}"/> {{disabled}} :: {{data}}', 
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      'data' : '=',
      'disabled' : '@'
    }
  }
})
```

This is my HTML

```
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.0" data-semver="1.2.0" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <div>
      this is my model = {{page.myModel}},
      {{!page.myModel.length}}
    </div>
    <div my-directive data="page.myModel" disabled="{{!page.myModel.length}}" ></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

This is the plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/weAC6NAjChjRPYktTnfO?p=preview

I expect the input field to be disabled once I delete its content. however it remains enabled. Can't understand why.

As a workaround for now I am watching 'disabled' on scope and using `elem.prop('disabled', true/false)` I manually change its state. would like to get rid of this code and use angular's binding power.

Answer (score 0):

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/C43JkD5ANdDgmteljXCN?p=preview)

Remove the curlies for ng-disabled:

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('myDirective', function(){
  return {
    template: '<input ng-model="data" ng-disabled="disabled"/> {{disabled}} :: {{data}}', 
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      'data' : '=',
      'disabled' : '@'
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: I expect the input to be enabled when there's content, and disabled when there's none. And you're wrong, I successfully added ng-disabled with {{}} that works both ways : http://plnkr.co/edit/C43JkD5ANdDgmteljXCN?p=preview

Comment: In your demo, you did exactly what i'm suggesting - you removed the curlies

Answer (score 0):

The reason that input is not being disabled is that [ng-disabled](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled) is expecting a truthy expression and this is why a boolean value such as checked will work perfectly.

```
Click me to toggle: <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked"><br/>
<button ng-model="button" ng-disabled="checked">Button</button>
```

If you bind ng-disabled to a function that returns a truthy value then you are passing the expected expression.

See this [codepen](http://codepen.io/NicholasMurray/pen/QwRwLX) and code below for a modified version of your code containing a bind to a function.

**JavaScript**

```
angular.module('myApp',[]);

angular.module('myApp').controller('myCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.page = { myModel : 'helloWorld' };
  console.log("myModel=" + $scope.page.MyModel);
})

angular.module('myApp').directive('myDirective', function(){
  return {
    template: '<input name="test" ng-model="data" ng-disabled="disabled()"/> {{disabledData}} :: {{data}} {{disabledData.length}}', 
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      'data' : '=',
      'disabledData' : '@'
    },
   link: function (scope, element) {
      scope.disabled = function(e){ 
                    if (scope.disabledData == 'true')
                return true;
                    else
                return false;
       };
    }
  }
})
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <h1>Hello Codepen!</h1>
    <div>
      this is my model = {{page.myModel}},
      {{!page.myModel.length}}
    </div>
  <div my-directive data="page.myModel" disabled-data="{{!page.myModel.length}}" ></div>
</div>
```